# jQuery: When not hovering over element X or Y, hide Y?

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, element

I have a few images lined up next to eachother, and whenever i hover one of the images, a tooltip appears for that image (with some information etc). The tooltip infomration is loaded with ajax, but that's irrelevant.

The problem is that the tooltip is loaded when i hover one of the images, and it disappears whenever i hover outside of it. So i am not able to hover over the tooltip, which i need to be able to.

So i thought of the solution to log every element i'm hovering over in an object. Like this:

```
$('*').mouseenter(function() {
    currently_hovering = $(this);
});
```

and then when i hover out of the image, check if the mouse is hovering over the tooltip, and if it is, then do nothing, if it's not, then hide the tooltip. Sounds good, right? But for some reason it refuses to log whenever i mouse over the tooltip. It still acts as if i am over the image (but the tooltip flashes terribly when i move the mouse around in it).

I am assuming it doesn't log over the tooltip because it is absolutely positioned? It is positioned above the image (that way i'm able to move the mouse to it without hiding the it). I've tried using mouseenter/mouseover and hover, all with the same result.

Are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem can be the fact that you are loading the information with ajax.

You need to use the live() function on data added to the page after the normal page load for scripts to work on the said data.

Sort of like this:

```
    $('.day').live('mouseover mouseout',function(e) {
        if (e.type === 'mouseover') {
            $(this).addClass('day-hover');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('day-hover');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, this did it. After some playing around with it i got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can wrap your image into for example `<div>` tag, have jquery "listen" on hover of that div tag and add your tooltip inside this tag right after image itself. Then hovering over tooltip shouldn't cause flickering, because you "dont leave" div that is causing it to be visible. Something like

```
<div class="imageWrapper">
  <img src="source" />
  <span class="tooltip">tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

then js would be something like

```
$('div.imageWrapper').hover(function(){
  var tooltipText = callWhateverMethodToLoadTooltipText();
  if($('span.tooltip',$(this)).length == 0)
    $(this).append('<span class="tooltip">' + tooltipText + '</span>');
  else
    $('span.tooltip',$(this)).text(tooltipText).show();
}, function(){
  $('span.tooltip', $(this)).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that the tooltip is loaded dynamically everytime i hover over an element with a certain class. Therefore i position it right before i close the body tag.

Comment: hmmmm, and do you have to add it right before end of body tag ? I'll try to describe what i mean in answer

Comment: Are you using the same tooltip element for every tooltip and changing the positioning? If not, you already have the image as a jQuery object, you could use `.parent()` to get the wrapper, then add the div as a child?

Comment: hmmmm but still you would need a wrapper that is wrapping only that one image i guess, or maybe you mean completely different solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The flashing will be because when you move the mouse over the tooltip, you're no longer hovering over that image and it's removing it, then when it's removed, you are all of a sudden hovering over the image again so it re-appears.

Sounds like the `onmouseout` call of the image is being called before the `onmouseover` of the tooltip when you hover over the tooltip, so your `currently_hovering` variable is not set to the tooltip.

Could you try using a timeout when you hover out of the image? Even a timeout of 0 seconds might work, just enough to let the browser process that the tooltip has been hovered over before it checks the value of `currently_hovering`?

Comment: I'll try using a timeout, but i doubt it will work for one reason. Even if i remove the hiding function that hides the tooltip when i hover out of the image, it doesn't recognize when i hover over the tooltip. I can hover over the tooltip (and it's childrens) as much as i want to, but it still doesn't show up in the log. I'll try it though, and get back as soon as i'm done. (I have to go away for about an our now so it might take some time, just so you know)

Comment: Aha, sounds like Mattis has cracked this one then. If you're dynamically creating the tooltip div, it won't have it's event handlers if you're using `bind()`, however if you use `live()`, when the object is created it will automatically bind the events.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a hidden tooltip element with a unique id on page load, then bind the events, then use your AJAX call function to change the innerHTML, positioning and show the tooltip.

Comment: Yeah that would be one solution Connel but i don't want to have to add a html element for every page i want this to work on. I just want to include a javascript file and have it working.

Comment: Could you have your included javascript file add the div when the page has loaded? `$(function() { createDiv(); });`

Comment: That's a possibility! I got it working now though, so no need for that. It's still a little glitchy, for example, if i move over the images really fast the last tooltip will stay open. Not sure how to fix that.

Comment: In case you're interested, i solved the glitch issues with a hoverintent plugin for jQuery. Works brilliant now. Thanks for all the help guys. Plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html